# Determing the following subsets of $\mathbb{R}^{2}$ when open, closed, bounded

Tags: real-analysis

- $A:=\{(x,y) \in \mathbb{N}^{2} : 1 \leq x, y \leq 10 \},$
- $B:=\{(x,y) \in \mathbb{Q}^{2} : 1 \leq x, y \leq 10 \},$
- $\mathbb{Q}^{2}.$

Please correct me if I'm wrong:

- closed and bounded,
- open and bounded,
- not sure.

Comment: Can you clarify your question what do you mean by "close and bounded, open and bounded not sure"

Comment: Those are my answers

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$A$ is indeed closed and bounded.

$B$ is bounded but it is not open, any ball centered in a point of $B$ will intersect $[1,10]^2 \setminus B$ because you will find a number with one (or both) irrational components as close as you want to the point you chose. Set $r>0$, and $p_0=(x_0,y_0) \in B$, then $\exists n \in \mathbb{N}$ such that $\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}} < r$. You can now consider $p + (\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}} ,0)$ which is in $B(p_0,r)$ but is not in $B$

Also it is not closed, consider a point in $[1,10]^2 \setminus B$,$\mathbb{Q}^2$ is dense in $\mathbb{R}^2$ so you should also be able to prove that any ball centered in a point of $[1,10]^2 \setminus B$ is not  contained in $[1,10]^2 \setminus B$.

Finally $\mathbb{Q}^2$ is not bounded but it is also neither open nor closed applying the same argument.

Comment: Can you give some more information about the second one please ?

Comment: @Nithish I have just edited my answer.